# How to decode raw packets in python?

Tags: python, network-programming

In perl there are the NetPacket modules to decode ethernet packets into ip, or ip into tcp.

```
my $data = $packet->{data};

my $eth_obj = NetPacket::Ethernet->decode($raw);

my $ip_obj = NetPacket::IP->decode($eth_obj->{data});
my $tcp_obj = NetPacket::TCP->decode($ip_obj->{data});
```

Is there a module in python to do the same?